# Jackson Specify type or date format for hashmap

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a `JSON` map which is coming to my rest service.

```
{
   "creationDateTimeFrom":"2015-01-15T11:27:00:000", //DATETIME
    "creationDateTimeTo":"2016-07-15T11:27:00:000", //DATETIME
    "eventIndicatorCd":["MAND", "CHOS"], //LIST
    "exDateFrom":"2015-01-01", //DATE
    "exDateTo":"2016-01-01", //DATE
    "lastUpdateDateTimeFrom":"2015-08-01T08:21:47:000", //DATETIME
    "lastUpdateDateTimeTo":"2015-08-06T08:21:47:000", //DATETIME
    "eventSecurityBlbTicker":["CCRO3 BS", "MSFT UW"], //LIST
    "eventTypeCd":["DVCA", "DVOP"], //LIST
    "statusCd":["CACS_CONF", "CACS_APPROVED"]   //LIST
}
```

And I have converter registered in `Spring` which convert map to object, and this map I am passing to my `JPA` specification `API` for criteria search.

```
Map<String, Object> objectMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

The problem is I have to convert date and datetime `String` value from map to `java.util.Date` format and replace it. Something similar to below.

```
map.put("exDateFrom", convertToDate(map.get("exDateFrom")));
```

Now I am thinking of below 2 solutions.

> Solution 1:

I implement `getUpdatedValueFor(String val)` function which will determine the type based on the format using regex and change the type in map. 
`map.replaceAll((key, val) -> getUpdatedValueFor(val));`

> Solution 2:

```
Map<String, Object> objectMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

Not sure whether it's possible or not, but during this conversion if I pass default `Date` format of jackson through which jackson can understand its a date and it automatically convert it to `java.util.Date` format as it's doing it for `java.util.List` without me specifying anything.

Does anyone know default date format for jackson `Date` or is there any way i can tell jackson if the string format is `2015-01-15T11:27:00:000` than convert it to date format ?

Comment: How do you convert `Mapt` to object? Could you use `POJO` instead `Map`? Does this `JSON` payload is constanta, I mean has a constant set of keys?

Comment: The user would like to keep it generic that's why map.